# Tweet Button Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, twitter

I'm trying to make a shortcut function so that if somebody presses Alt+T they can tweet the article. I have the shortcut part sorted so ignore that part, it's just tweeting the title and URL of the page. Here's what I have so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
shortcut.add("Alt+T",function() {
window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=(document.title) - &url=(document.URL)&via=jamiebrittain")
});
</script>
```

It seems that `document.title` and `document.url` aren't changing to page title and URL. This is all in a script tag stating it's javascript so why is not changing or does `document.title` and `document.url` not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=(document.title) - &url=(document.URL)&via=jamiebrittain")
```

do

```
window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+encodeURIComponent(document.title)+"&url="+ encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+"&via=jamiebrittain")
```

you need to concatenate the string with the javascript variables instead of using them inline.

Thanks @Esailija for pointing out that you need to use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)  too - this ensures that the variables are encoded before being added to the string

Comment: @Esailija around the URL ? or title as well ?

Comment: `document.title`, `document.URL` I am also not sure about the plain spaces in there, they should probably be `%20`?

Comment: It seems to tweets `(Example Page Title) -  via @jamiebrittain`. It's missing the URL and wrapping the page title in brackets. The result is still the same even if I changed the white space to `%20`.

Comment: @user1505209 remove the brackets around the URL and the Title and it works fine - see my updated answer

Comment: @ManseUK Yep, all fine now. Thanks a bunch for your help, I accepted your answer and you're awesome :)